# How to enable/disable many controls together?

Tags: asp.net, panel

I have many checkBoxes HTML controls runat server, I want to disable and enable them together. 
I've tried to set them in an ASP.Net Panel and set the panel disabled, but they stayed enabled.

Any idea ?

**The code**

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PrivilegesCheckList" >
    <input id="adminPrivilegeCheckBox" type="checkbox" runat="server" />
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, itemAdminPrivilege%>" />
    <br />
    <input id="accountPrivilegeCheckBox" type="checkbox" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, itemAccountManagerPrivilege%>" />
    <br />
    <input id="employeePrivilegeCheckBox" type="checkbox" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, itemEmployeeManagerPrivilege%>" />
    <br />
    <input id="orgChartPrivilegeCheckBox" type="checkbox" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, itemOrgChartPrivilege%>" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: this may help:

[How do I disable all controls in ASP.NET page?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505353/how-do-i-disable-all-controls-in-asp-net-page

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-disable-all-controls-in-ASP-NET-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Panel to disabled would work for asp Controls like CheckBox but not for an input with runat=server. This checkbox is disabled because the panel has Enabled=false:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Enabled="false" >
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" /> 
</asp:Panel>
```

You could also easily fix this with jquery (client side):

```
$('#mypanelClientID input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript you may do something like this :

```
var controls = document.getElementById("<%=panel1.ClientID%>").getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++)
     controls[i].disabled = true;
```

Note that ASP.Net produces dynamic Id's for server side controls (panel here ) , that tends to use document.getElementById("<%=panel1.ClientID%>") above.

Comment: Thanks, but I would do that from server side, isn't it possible?

Comment: That's possible, you could write a custom control for that. But is there a reason you don't use asp:CheckBox instead of your checkbox?