# enable/disable radiobuttonlist with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to enable/disable radiobuttonlist with javascript code. This javascript is working fine with textboxes but it looks like that it doesn't work with radiobuttonlist.
Here is the code I am using:

```
 var chkEPM = document.getElementById("<%=chkEPM.ClientID %>");
        chkEPM.onchange = function () {
            if (this.checked == true)
                document.getElementById("<%=rblEPM.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
            else
                document.getElementById("<%=rblEPM.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
        };
```

Thanks in advance for each reply and have a good day/night

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function changeItemState(disable)
{
    rb = document.getElementById("<%=rblEPM.ClientID %>");

    var rbItems = rb.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < rbItems.length; itemIndex++) 
    {
        rbItems[itemIndex].disabled = disable;
    }
}

var chkEPM = document.getElementById("<%=chkEPM.ClientID %>");
chkEPM.onchange = function () {
    if (this.checked == true)
        changeItemState(false);
    else
        changeItemState(true);
};
```

Or if you can use jquery 1.6 or greater you could do:

```
$("#<%=rblEPM.ClientID %>").find('input').prop('disabled', 'true');
```

Comment: is there a way how can I utilize that for multiple radiobuttonlists, I can see that the elementID is hardcoded in the function?

Comment: never mind, I figured that out, I am passing the var 'chkEPM' in this case to the function and use that there :). Thanks again

Comment: I had no problem disabling it from `rblEPM` control directly. I wonder what the problem was that needed it to be done to each child control. Any idea?

Comment: @Shredder - Actually it looks like disabling the rblEPM control directly should not work. ASP.NET renders the RadioButtonList as an HTML table If you look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp), table elements do not have a disabled attribute. It works in IE but I just tried Chrome and it doesn't work.

Comment: @kevev22 Ah, I was doing it in IE. I'll mess around with it when I get to work. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
document.getElementById('rbl').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

`rbl` being the ID of your radiobuttonlist.

Comment: @Laziale then maybe you should check that `document.getElementById('radiobtnListID')` is actually returning the DOM object. You can use javascript debugging tools like Firebug.

Comment: I am getting this error when I am using IE debugging tool: "Unable to get value of the property 'setAttribute': object is null"

Comment: @Laziale Could you show all the code that relates to this? Including the asp.net/html markup.

Comment: @Laziale sounds like you're trying to use it as a variable, not a function.

Comment: Shredder's code, and yours as well, is correct.  There is a good chance that the browser you are using is so old that it does not support the 'disabled' attribute for table elements

Comment: @rkw I am using firefox, and it was updated this morning with the latest version :)

Comment: As I stated in the comments to my own answer, the RadioButtonList is output as an HTML table which [does not officially have a disabled attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp). If you set the RadioButtonList as Enabled="false" server side you will see that ASP.NET will set each of the individual Radio Buttons as disabled. For some reason in IE you can set the table as disabled, but I just tried it in Chrome and it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function EnableDisableRadio(CheckBox1) {
            var controls = document.getElementById("<%=Panel1.ClientID%>").getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++)
                controls[i].disabled = CheckBox1.checked ? false : true;
        }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include some explanation about why this "work 100%", as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6908533/1677912).

Answer (score 0):

For cross platform support u need to use something like this one:

```
$('#RadioButtonList1').find('*').each(function () 
{ 
    $(this).attr("disabled", true); 
});
```

Comment: There is no jQuery tag in the question.